# Zapier/OpenAI/Webhook Issue (Call Recording Link w/ Security Check)

Tags: openai-api, zapier, openai-whisper

- I'm trying to create an Automation in my zapier account that does The Following: starts off with a webhook trigger that submits all the necessary information to zapier, then from the information contained in that web hook it will then takes a public URL for a call recording from my phone system (smrtphone.io), and transcribes it using openAI.
- the problem is that once it gets to the part where it's supposed to transcribe it, my zap comes across this error...

"*The app returned "Just a moment...Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue(function(){window._cf_chl_opt={cvId: '2',cZone: "rec.phone.smrt.studio",cType: 'non-interactive',cNounce: '78416',cRay: '80d5dda93a3c59f8',cHa...*".

- when I brought this up to zapier customer service, their thoughts were that it seems when you try to load the public URL for that call recording the hosting service provider forces a brief little security check before it loads the actual audio file. And they're only suggestion was to have the security check turned off (which is not possible - I've Been Told).

Here's an example of a call recording URL showing the security check that happens before it loads the actual audio recording...

https://rec.phone.smrt.studio/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC34358e38ada4276f05db5b4ca68b351c/Recordings/RE97dad3fb9a4292ce0321a2a50830353d

- At this point I'm not sure what to try. I'm curious if there is a way to force the system to wait for the security check to be done and then transcribe it? Or maybe there's a way to download the file and then upload it again through another zapier step? I'm just shooting in the dark here. I'm not really sure what the solution needs to be.
- I would love any ideas on a workaround to accomplish the above goal.

Comment: If I’m understanding correctly, this is a Cloudflare-provided security mechanism that the `smrtphone.io` service provider is leveraging. These types of services are usually employed to defeat such automated scraping of assets, which it seems to have done successfully. What did that provider’s support have to say? Are these URLs supposed to be accessed in this manner?

Comment: For what it’s worth, [`smrtphone.io`’s Terms and Conditions document](https://www.smrtphone.io/terms-and-conditions/) explicitly prohibit the use of “*any robot, spider, other automatic device, or manual process to monitor, copy, or “scrape” web pages or the content contained in the Site or for any other unauthorized purpose without Our prior written consent;*” Sounds like what you’re running into is just their enforcement of this clause.

Comment: @esqew - I'm still waiting to hear back from smrtphone, my question/request was just pushed to their development team.